# Cannot delete or drop a Teradata database using ARCMAIN/BTEQ (version: 15.00)

Tags: teradata

I am using ARCMAIN to delete and restore a database for our Disaster Recovery (DR). I have already made a production database backup, which is good. I then pointed my restore ARCMAIN script to the backup file and performed the following restore.

```
.LOGON server_name/sysdba,"password";
DELETE DATABASE (db_name);
COPY DATA TABLES (db_name),
RELEASE LOCK,
FILE=DBARC;
.LOGOFF;
```

My restore was stuck in the DELETE database step. I tried the following SQL to kill the locks, but it did not help.

```
LOGGING ONLINE ARCHIVE OFF FOR db_name;
RELEASE LOCK db_name, OVERRIDE;
```

Any suggestions? I assume that there are locks that prevented me from deleting the database.

Thanks

Comment: You may need to use Viewpoint or PMAPI functions (or possibly lokdisp console utility) to identify the locks in question.

Comment: I will give it a try today.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue was the active user sessions that locks the DB, so that I cannot delete it.

First to select running sessions, then you delete a user or a session.

```
SELECT * FROM DBC.SessionInfoV;
SELECT SYSLIB.AbortSessions (-1, 'ARC1', 0, 'Y', 'Y');
SELECT SYSLIB.ABORTSESSIONS (-1, '*',1065 , 'Y', 'Y');
```